# GDB - Prepare commands for interactive mode

Tags: gdb

I want to run some commands in gdb and then be in the interactive mode. How can I do that? If I run:

```
gdb -ex "b main.c:390" -ex 'r' --args ./main -b1 < in.txt
```

gdb then exits. I don't want that.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must create `.gdbinit` file in the folder where you have executable. Contents of `.gdbinit` must be as folows:

```
file main
set args -b1 < in.txt
break main.c:390
run
```

Then just invoke `gdb` in console.

**EDIT**

just invoke `gdb -ex "file main" -ex "break main.c:390" -ex "run" -ex "set args -b1 < test"`

Comment: Thanks Oleg! This works as expected. But is it possible to do this as one command from the command line? Edit the .gdbinit file each time seems superfluous to me.

Comment: Well, your command its't that different than mine, but it works as expected! Thank you Oleg! :)

Comment: @TomášNesrovnal Don't forget to delete `.gdbinit` file If you want to work via command line.

Comment: One little nit: the command "run" must be run after the args are set. So the right answer to my question is:
gdb -ex "file main" -ex "b main.c:390" -ex "set args -b1 < in.txt" -ex "r"

Comment: @TomášNesrovnal All works for me in the sequence that I gave